# How to regularize the latent variables of a kalman filter to be small?

Tags: kalman-filters, optimization, convex-optimization, bayesian-estimation, regularization

This is perhaps a bit of a weird idea but suppose I want the latent variables of a Kalman filter to be small (like as if the states were being regularized). This is kind of like putting an extra prior on each latent variable at each time step t as a normal centered around 0. I'm pretty sure this could be done with a particle filter but thats too slow for me.

Any help or areas to look into would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The idea of a Kalman filter is that the filter is designed using an accurate model of some process.  If you're arbitrarily adding modifying the dynamics of the latent variables, then you're deliberately breaking that model.  All in all, your question sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Please _edit your question_ to explain your situation, the problem you're having with it, and why you think your proposed solution will help.

Comment: Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Kalman Filter has a form as an optimization problem:

$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{ \left\{\boldsymbol{x}_{l}\right\}_{l = 0}^{k} } \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left( \boldsymbol{x}_{0} - \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{0} \right)}^{T} \boldsymbol{P}_{0}^{-1} \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{0} - \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{0} \right) \\ & + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{l = 0}^{k} {\left( \boldsymbol{z}_{l} - \boldsymbol{H}_{l} \boldsymbol{x}_{l} \right)}^{T} \boldsymbol{R}_{l}^{-1} \left( \boldsymbol{z}_{l} - \boldsymbol{H}_{l} \boldsymbol{x}_{l} \right) \\ & + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{l = 0}^{k} \boldsymbol{w}_{l}^{T} \boldsymbol{Q}_{l}^{-1} \boldsymbol{w}_{l} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{x}_{l + 1} & = \boldsymbol{F}_{l} \boldsymbol{x}_{l} + \boldsymbol{G}_{l} \boldsymbol{w}_{l}, \; l = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, k - 1
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$

In the case of stationary Kalman Filter the above becomes:

$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{ \left\{\boldsymbol{x}_{l}\right\}_{l = 0}^{k} } \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left( \boldsymbol{x}_{0} - \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{0} \right)}^{T} \boldsymbol{P}_{0}^{-1} \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{0} - \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{0} \right) \\ & + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{l = 0}^{k} {\left( \boldsymbol{z}_{l} - \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{x}_{l} \right)}^{T} \boldsymbol{R}^{-1} \left( \boldsymbol{z}_{l} - \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{x}_{l} \right) \\ & + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{l = 0}^{k} \boldsymbol{w}_{l}^{T} \boldsymbol{Q}^{-1} \boldsymbol{w}_{l} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{x}_{l + 1} & = \boldsymbol{F} \boldsymbol{x}_{l} + \boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{w}_{l}, \; l = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, k - 1
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$

Both problem are [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problem which can be easily solved.

So in general you could add some regularization by adding the term $ \lambda \sum_{l = 0}^{k} \phi \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{l} \right) $ to the objective function.
In your case, in order to have low value, you may use the $ {L}_{2} $ norm by adding $ \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{l = 0}^{k} {\left\| \boldsymbol{x}_{l} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $.

The question is, for what purpose?

The Kalman Filter is the MMSE estimator under the assumption the model is Gaussian (Actually for nay linear). Since it already impose some prior on the variables I don't find adding another prior (Which is actually equivalent) making sense.

Yet mathematically, the above allows it as you asked.

Comment: Is the constraint linear? It seems recursive.

Comment: @Mark, You can still write it in a linear matrix form. The matrix will be block diagonal like.